# Django Rest Framework - How to return all info from a model in a Response when getting Object of type model is not JSON serializable?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return an object with more information after a user logs in.

```
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        player = Player.objects.get(id=user.pk)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email,
            'full_user_info': player, # Object of type Player is not JSON serializable
        })
```

I've tried `dict(player)` but then the error reads `TypeError: 'Player' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Player [model](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) serializer

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

And then use the serializer in your response dict:

```
{ 
    # other fields
    "full_user_info": PlayerSerializer(data=Player)
}
```

Comment: ```raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type PlayerSerializer is not JSON serializable```

Comment: new problem, and I don't know how to do this: ```AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.```

Comment: If you want to be sure that your serializer data is valid, you should use serialized.is_valid() before using serializer.data.  Otherwise, if im not mistaken remove the data keyword from serializer PlayerSerializer(Player) and use it directly (serializer.data)